# React ag-grid grouping collapses whenever row gets updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am feeding data to ag-grid via redux state. I have a button in each row using which I can update the specific row data. When I update, API is called and newly updated data will come from API and it is updated in redux state which in turn gets updated in Grid.

I am achieving this using the `deltaRowDataMode`. This `deltaRowDataMode` will only update specific row data. Data update is working fine. But when I group a column, expand the rows and then update a row data, ag-grid collapsing the grouping, though update is happening fine. For sorting, filtering it is working beautifully.

I tried `rememberGroupStateWhenNewData`, it is not working. I check many functionalities like expandAll, etc., but none of them suits my condition. Is there any build in functionality or approach which prevents AG-Grid from collapsing the grouping when update happens?

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share any code anywhere. Sorry about that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

below grid options helped me fix this issue:

rememberGroupStateWhenNewData: true,
suppressScrollOnNewData: true,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case - which might be slightly different to your case - it helped to use the getRowId-Feature of AgGrid (see the docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-row-data/#example-simple-row-id))

```
const getRowId = useMemo<GetRowIdFunc>(() => {
  return (params: GetRowIdParams) => params.data?.id ?? null;
}, []);
```

---

```
<AgGridReact
  ..
  getRowId={getRowId}
  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain a [immutable data store](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-row-data/#example-simple-immutable-store) to keep track of rows so that open group remains open and don't collapse on updating of data.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AG Grid documentation site](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update/), there is a linked video that explains that the use of `getRowId` will allow the grid to maintain state appropriately.